# Element UI - Upload component not waiting for confirmation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using the last version of `vue-js` and `element-ui`

This question addresses the `upload` component whose documentation can be found [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload)

#### Situation

A hook function `before-upload` allows us to check some stuff before allowing the upload to be accomplished.

#### Problem

When using a confirmation dialog, the upload does not wait the user to be accomplished

#### Question

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

https://jsfiddle.net/buoy2m4o/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *return* the promise.

```
beforeAvatarUpload(file) {
  return this.$confirm('Are you sure to upload this?', 'Warning', {
    confirmButtonText: 'OK',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    type: 'warning'
  }).then(() => {
    // do stuff
  })
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vjx09gh/1/).

Comment: I do need the handlers since I will do further validation. That said, your version is perfectly working but if I leave the handlers it does not work : success is displayed even if one cancel https://jsfiddle.net/3vjx09gh/

Comment: @Leo do you do anything in the `catch`? If you remove that, then it works.

Comment: I don't. Weird... Thank you!

Comment: @Leo Technically what happens if *you* handle the catch is that the returned promise is resolved, not rejected. If *you* don't handle the rejection, then it passes on down to the Upload component which acts as if someone decided to cancel the upload.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Bert